# Is there a way of setting conditional formatting based on cell colour which has been activated by conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am looking to try and solve a workflow issue and could really use some help, I'm learning as I go and have been trying to solve this for a little while now without any luck.

I want to set a conditional format which is activated if any of the conditional formatting in that row has been activated already.

I'm really unsure of how to express cell colour in a formula and have tried using the name manager for this but honestly, I'm in a muddle. any suggestions?

I think basically I want to be able to set a formula that says something along the lines of

=IF(B5:BL5=Cellcolour5) then format blue.

I'm trying to help my dad out with a spreadsheet for a small charity he runs and it's just gotten a bit more complicated than I can handle with my limited experience. Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test for cell colour in a formulas without vba.

Since this is for charity , if you want I will personally help you out with excel -  you can contact me directly at stevenmartin99@gmail.com